# Looking for Dynamica Package

Tags: packages

I have been trying to download the package Dynamica for Mathematica, included with Discrete Dynamical Systems and Difference Equations with Mathematica, by Mustafa R.S. Kulenovic and Orlando Merino. I know this has been asked before but I still cant get it anywhere. Could someone send to me please?

Comment: I see that this is a duplicate, but I'm curious to check it out too.  Here's the closest I've gotten: https://web.archive.org/web/20151201070243/http://www.math.uri.edu/Dynamica/DynamicaDownload.html.  I'll email the authors to see if they'll share it.

Comment: Another lead... https://meetings.ams.org/math/spring2021e/meetingapp.cgi/Paper/4341